# If $N \lhd G$ and $A \lhd B \le G$ then $AN \lhd BN$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

The content of the question is in the title. I'm asking this in relation to a proof that (assuming the above conditions): $$BN/AN \cong B/A(B \cap N)$$
Which I believe follows directly from an application of the second isomorphism theorem for groups.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

$AN \subseteq BN$ is clear since $A \subseteq B$.

Then we must show that $xANx^{-1} \subseteq AN$ for $x \in BN$.

$x=bn$ so show that $bn(an_{1})n^{-1}b^{-1} \in AN.$

Using the normality of $N$ in $G$ and of $A$ in $B$ as well the extensive use of the generalized associative law for groups,

$bn(an_{1})n^{-1}b^{-1} = b(na)n_{1}n^{-1}b^{-1}=b(an_{2})(n_{3}b^{-1})= (ba)n_{2}(n_{3}b^{-1})=(a_{2}b)n_{2}(b^{-1}n_{4})=a_{2}(bn_{2})(b^{-1}n_{4})=a_{2}(n_{5}b)(b^{-1}n_{4})=(a_{2}n_{5})(b^{-1}b)n_{4}=(a_{2}n_{5})n_{4}=a_{2}(n_{5}n_{4})=a_{2}n_{6} \in AN$.

Comment: @Bungo yeah im just confusing myself at this point trying to write this...

Comment: This was very ugly before, so I hope the person that downvoted reconsiders! It might be easier/less confusing just to show the "free" general movement of elements in normal subgroups by induction than doing this...

Comment: Thank you Derek. I've accepted your answer, but I have found a cleaner way to do the algebraic manipulation: for $a \in A$, $b \in B$, $n,m \in N$ we have $$m^{-1}b^{-1}anbm = m^{-1}b^{-1}abb^{-1}nbm = m^{-1}a'n'm = a'n''n'm \in AN$$

Comment: Can the downvoters explain? By normality, swap the order and adding a subscript each time.

Comment: Great, unfortunately I have a sensitive guy (people?) on this site downvoting my posts so it will stay at $-1$ haha.